# Use SSL certificate with CURL on macOS (Sierra)

Tags: macos, ssl, curl, tls1.2

I am trying to reach an HTTPS site via curl on a Mac.  The following returns a valid response:

`curl --cert <path_to_cert_p12>:<password> -H <header> -XPOST https://secret_site.com`

However, I don't want to enter a password on the command line or hardcode it in a shell script.

I have imported the certificate to Keychain and can visit the site in a web browser without having to supply a password.  Is there some way to tell curl to use the certificate from Keychain?

I am using standard curl, not a homebrew installation.

Comment: I ended up bundling this into a Perl script using read_password (from Term::ReadPassword) and passing that to a capturex call (from IPC::System::Simple).  On Mac, the password portion of the curl call is hidden from ps -ef calls.  It's not ideal and I wouldn't want to use it on a shared server, but for a small laptop script, it works.  I'd still be interested in other suggestions though.

Comment: Not sure whether that still is an issue for you, but the Homebrew version of curl supports the use of the Keychain when using the `--cert` parameter, as outlined here: https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2014-10/0053.html